# Why is Hashem's name attached to only some of His accomplishments in Tehillim 146?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, tehilim-psalms

[Psalms 146:6](http://mechon-mamre.org/i/t/t26e6.htm)ff lists twelve of Hashem's deeds:

> עֹשֶׂה שָׁמַיִם וָאָרֶץ
>   אֶת הַיָּם וְאֶת כָּל אֲשֶׁר בָּם
>   הַשֹּׁמֵר אֱמֶת לְעוֹלָם
>   עֹשֶׂה מִשְׁפָּט לָעֲשׁוּקִים
>   נֹתֵן לֶחֶם לָרְעֵבִים
>   ה' מַתִּיר אֲסוּרִים
>   ה' פֹּקֵחַ עִוְרִים
>   ה' זֹקֵף כְּפוּפִים
>   ה' אֹהֵב צַדִּיקִים
>   ה' שֹׁמֵר אֶת גֵּרִים
>   יָתוֹם וְאַלְמָנָה יְעוֹדֵד
>   וְדֶרֶךְ רְשָׁעִים יְעַוֵּת
>
> He makes heaven and earth,
>   the seas and all that is in them;
>   He keeps truth forever.
>   He executes justice for the oppressed,
>   He gives food to the hungry;
>   G-d releases the bound.
>   G-d opens the eyes of the blind,
>   G-d straightens the bowed,
>   G-d loves the righteous.
>   G-d watches over the strangers;
>   He encourages the orphan and widow,
>   and makes crooked the way of the wicked.

Why is Hashem's name attached only to items six through ten on the list, and omitted from the first four and the last two? Is it simply so that each stich has three words apiece,* or is there some deeper explanation?

---

<sub>* Except #2 and #10 (and in the latter, את is short enough to be effectively part of the next word - indeed, they are attached with a makaf).</sub>

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that the ibn Ezra [(to pasuk 8)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14255&st=&pgnum=528) addresses this: The reason is that the ones in which Hashem's name is mentioned are the ones in which the victim has to turn to Hashem and can't get help from people. He answers some of the places in the pesukim that are inconsistent with his explanation, but leaves some unaddressed.